# How to show layer when select another layer?

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript

I have an `OpenaLayers/gxp` application. I have base and overlay layers groups. I want to show some overlay layers when select base layer. For example when I choose `BaseLayer1` I want to show `OverlayLayer1 and OverlayLayer2` automatically.

I seek something in `gxp` but can't find anything interesting in class `gxp.plugins.LayerTree`.  So I think only OpenLayers can help me. Is it possible to show layers when I choose another layer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should listen to the BaseLayer's [visibilitychanged](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Layer-js.html) event, and then change the visibility of your OverLay layers